# Under what cirumstances would type 'System.Object' qualify for serialization?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, object, formatting

I'm in charge of a comprehensive serialization format with support to serialize runtime objects (any derived type of `Object`). I can't find a sane scenario where one would choose to serialize an instance of `System.Object` immediately. In my purview, `Object` is undefinitive, and belongs in a binary format, not in a human-readable text.

With the introduction of Generics, instances of type `Object` should no longer identify data. Any insights to get me over the edge? For consideration, note that both Data Contracts and JSON.NET support serialization of `System.Object`.

Comment: Generics don't erase types; they merely defer their selection.

Answer (score 4):

> In my purview, Object is undefinitive, and belongs in a binary format, not in a human-readable text.

I don't see the relationship between these two things; there are plenty of good reasons to choose text versus binary: this is not one of them. How it appears is an implementation detail *only*.

> any derived type of Object

The biggest challenge, then, is deciding how you are going to encode the *type* data. In many serializers, the answer is simply: you don't. This avoids an entire family of problems with refactoring and version (renaming types, assembly-names, etc). You *could* limit yourself to `[Serializable]` types, but by the time you've done that you might as well just use the (terrible, IMO) `BinaryFormatter`. Of course, some key questions here might be: why do you want to write your own serializer? What is the feature(s) you are after that aren't satisfied by the existing platform tools and 3rd-party / open-source tools?

Then you have a range of protocol / formatting considerations; mapping serialized data back into types is ... non-trivial. If the type is going to require configuration (think: `[XmlElement(...)]` etc), you could reasonably limit yourself to types that have the basic configuration evidence. This is *kinda* what `DataContractSerializer` does, except it falls back into a more basic field-level serializer if that configuration data is missing.

I'm also a big advocate for the view that entity models make *lousy* serialization types, so it is quite reasonable to expect there to exist a DTO model that broadly reflects your serialization needs; and if that is the case, it is not unreasonable to expect that the DTO type might be annotated in some way (or at least advertised to the serializer in some way - perhaps at runtime if attributes aren't an option).

Comment: The difference that I recognize is; human-readable text is determined to presentation while binary formats are typically determined to accuracy, because all complexities can be afforded. The problem is: Why would a type designed for serialization contain indefinite members? Sure there is `IList`, but I'd rather qualify such class as obsolete.

Comment: @toplel32 I disagree with your description; SOAP isn't intended to be presented; XML is *barely* human readable in most cases. Json is *more* readable, but I'd say that even that says **nothing** about the intent.

Comment: @toplel32 your comment on `IList` is very valid; but it gets more complicated; what patterns *do* you want to support? Not everything is `IList<T>`. It could be `IEnumerable<T>` with a good-looking `Add`.  It could even not be `IEnumerable<T>` but have a custom `GetEnumerator()` type that is strongly typed. Lots of very awkward questions. Then there's dictionaries, etc. Again: **why** do you want to write your own? What is the feature you want to add that isn't already available?

Comment: Why is BinaryFormatter terrible?  Is it slow?  Is it brittle?  Is Protocol Buffers better?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it is *incredibly* brittle re refactoring and versioning, and unless you do all the work yourself (`ISerializable` etc) it is brittle towards internal field changes; it isn't cross-platform, and has a nasty habit of sucking in events and serializing unexpected objects. I've seen lots of people get into messes where they can't deserialize their data back via `BinaryFormatter`, so yes: it has some issues. protobuf-net deliberately avoids the worst of these problems; although to be fair: *all* serializers have scenarios they are strong at / weak at.

Comment: @MarcGravell - Microsoft habitually implements XML for all casual serialization problems. While such intent is good and uniform, I'd take it with a grain of salt with respect to efficiency.

Comment: @MarcGravell - While both human-readable and binary formats can prefer any degree of complexity, it is counter-intuitive for human-readable formats to cross certain boundaries; for example, private members are skipped by type contracting functions to avoid direct exposure to humans, similarly human-readable formats are flat to avoid a spagetti of references. I agree, this are merely typical features. The thing is; to make a human-readable format satisfactory, it is right to have severe limitations.

Comment: @MarcGravell - To jump to my intent for creating a new serializer; I'm not just starting, the project is near completion. I cannot reveal any specifics yet, but note that this concerns an original solution, no aimless tinkering. It has a whole new purpose.

Comment: @toplel32 actually MS has been doing more and more json - for example, the DNX ("vNext") project files are json, not xml. Re private members: IIRC, `DataContractSerializer` (which is xml-based) emits fields,  not properties, if the type is not annotated - likewise `NetDataContractSerializer`. Likewise, formats that are *intended* to be human-readable often are *not* flat; unless you actually mean tree vs graph. As someone who has written fairly fully-developed serializers: good luck. But I think some of your questions are concerning for a tool approaching completion rather than conception.

Comment: @MarcGravell - Microsoft _appears_ quite uncomfortable with JSON, it may be a comprimise rather than an interest. I assume that 'tree' is more accurate, 'flat' usually works, while unorthodox.

Comment: @MarcGravell - I was aware of this concern prior to starting the project, but it hasn't been a priority till now. Eitherway, I could notify you when this libary is complete to make some sense out of this, if you're interested.

Comment: @toplel32 if your plan is to make it publicly available, then sure: shoot me an email or ping me here when you release it; I'm "more than competent" in serialization technology and techniques

Comment: @MarcGravell - Yes, it will be released as open-source. I'll note your details then.